# Django 2.1 link as field in DjangoAdmin List

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've read every question here regarding this issue but unfortunately none of them is working for me.

My goal is to show custom column in Django Admin `ModelAdmin` as HTTP Link (`<a>` tag).

`admin.py`

```
def device_url(dev_id, dev_name):
    html = '/v1/admin/devices/device/{}/change/'.format(dev_id)
    return format_html('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>', html, dev_name)

@admin.register(Machine)
class MachineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MachineForm
    list_display = ('name', 'location', 'devices', 'last_maintenance_log')
    inlines = [CommentInline, ]

    def devices(self, obj):
        devices_with_links = ', '.join([device_url(d.id, d.name) for d in obj.devices.all()])
        if len(devices_with_links) > 1:
            return devices_with_links
        else:
            return '-'

    devices.allow_tags = True
```

But it is still escaping those and showing it as plaintext.

`Devices` is `device_set` from `Machine` model. 1 Machine : N Devices relationship.

According to what I've read here, it should just work, even without the `allow_tags=True` when using `format_html`.

Is this not working because I dont have format_html in the inner function `devices`? If not, does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 2.0 the support for allow_tags in ModelAdmin methods was [removed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0):

> Support for the allow_tags attribute on ModelAdmin methods will be removed.

It seems you will instead want to use [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
return mark_safe(devices_with_links)
```

Comment: I realised and answered that before you did, but you are correct so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I just solved this by changing

`return devices_with_links`

to

`return mark_safe(devices_with_links)`